# Monitor the Jetty-based Java application using Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: java, jetty, prometheus, grafana, jmx

I have deployed a Java application in the server (in 8091) using `nohup` and Jetty.

I need to monitor that application using Prometheus and Grafana.

So downloaded the JMX exporter.

Need to get all the available metrics (JMX exporter) for that application monitoring.

Downloaded the below jar file:

```
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.1.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.1.0.jar
```

Config.yaml

```
[root@localhost software]# cat config.yaml
---
startDelaySeconds: 0
hostPort: 127.0.0.1:7101
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7101/jmxrmi
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: true
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

The deployment command which I used for usual deployment: (in this directory, Jetty was present)

```
nohup  -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000 -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=temp_dir -jar jetty-runner-9.0.7.v20131107.jar --log yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-request.log --out yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-output.log --port 8091 --path /java-application-1 hotfix.war >> java-application-1.log 2>&1 &
```

it works fine ..

When I tried to monitor the application with JMX exporter, I used the below command:

```
nohup java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.1.0.jar=7101:config.yaml -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000 -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=epoch_temp_dir -jar jetty-runner-9.0.7.v20131107.jar --log yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-request.log --out yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-output.log --port 8091 --path /java-application-1 hotfix.war >> java-application-1.log 2>&1 &
```

> it reports as  :  [1]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup
> java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.1.0.jar=7101:config.yaml
> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000 -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Djava.io.tmpdir=epoch_temp_dir -jar jetty-runner-9.0.7.v20131107.jar --log
> yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-request.log --out
> yyyy_mm_dd-java-application-1-output.log --port 8091 --path
> /java-application-1 hotfix.war >> java-application-1.log 2>&1

In log file  :
It reports as :

```
nohup: ignoring input
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At most one of hostPort and jmxUrl must be provided
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.loadConfig(JmxCollector.java:120)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.<init>(JmxCollector.java:74)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:36)
        ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

I m not sure whether the `config.yaml` and the command which I used for monitoring the deployed Java application was correct.

How to monitor this Jetty-based java application using Prometheus and Grafana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the both `Hostport and JMXURL` in config.yaml worked for me ..

```
 [root@localhost software]# cat config.yaml
    ---
    startDelaySeconds: 0
    ssl: false
    lowercaseOutputName: true
    lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
    rules:
    - pattern: ".*"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have specified both `hostPort` and `jmxUrl` keys in `config.yaml`. But **at most one** of them must be provided. Remove one of them.

Comment: Now it is running fine; I have added the IP:port under the target section of the prometheus.yml in the prometheus server and restarted the Prometheus.  But Prometheus status page shows "down" for this server. So Grafana is not loading the data.  Reason : its getting timedout; process is running in the server `netstat`. `curl localhost:port` in the java application deployed server also waiting for long period of time

Comment: `Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
        Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`   --- Error log

Comment: I have opened the port 7101(JMX) in the client server. Granted access to Prometheus server to access the port in the client server